# how to update a row of a mysql database with retrofit 2?

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to `update` a specific row of a mysql database using `retrofit2` in `android studio` following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKEFGsMUG8s. I did that with the `create` and `read` methods and it works but for `update` I have more difficulties. I have a `API interface` and a php script to send requests to my database.

My problem is: when I use the method `updateTest` by clicking on a button, the response tell me that the request was a success but I see no updated row in my database.

This is the API interface:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApiTest {

@PUT("update.php/{id}")
Call<Test> putTest(@Path("id") int id, @Body Test test);
}
```

This is the update method:

```
private void updateTest(){

    Test test = new Test ("updated_name", "updated_age");

    Call<Test> call = jsonPlaceHolderApiTest.putTest(3, test);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Test>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Test> call, Response<Test> response) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityTest.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Test> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityTest.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the php script:

```
<?php

mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    require_once 'db_config.php';

    $sql = "UPDATE `test` SET name= '$name', age = '$age' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, $sql));
    if (mysqli_query($check)) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "successfully";
    } else {
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Failure!";
    }
} else {
    $response["value"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Error!";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($check)` will not work because this function requires two arguments and even the one you are passing is incorrect. Was it supposed to be `if($check)` ?

Comment: `$db` and `$sql` are my two arguments. `$db` is used to connect to my database and it works in others files.
`if($check)`: I've used it for the create method, I've tried to remove it but I have an other error: `java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $`.

Comment: I was talking about this line only: `if (mysqli_query($check)) {`

Comment: The result is the same with `if($check){
    
       $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "successfully";
    
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by changing the php script, the API interface and the update method.

```
<?php

include("db_config.php");


function updateData($id,$name,$age){
global $db;
$result=mysqli_query($db , "UPDATE `test` SET `name`='$name',
`age`='$age' WHERE id = '$id'")or die(mysqli_error($db));
return $result;
}

$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];

if (isset($id) && isset($name) && isset($age)){
    $result=updateData($id,$name,$age);

if ($result) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Successfully updated"; 
    echo json_encode($response);
} 
else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 
    echo json_encode($response);
}

} 
else {
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";  
  echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

In the API interface, I've replaced `@PUT` by `@POST`:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update.php")
Call<Test> updateTest2(
        @Field("id") int id,
        @Field("name")String name,
        @Field("age")String age);
```

This is the new update method:

```
 private void updateTest2(int id, String name, String age) {


    JsonPlaceHolderApiTest jsonPlaceHolderApiTest =ApiClient.getApiClient().create(JsonPlaceHolderApiTest.class);
    Call<Test> call = jsonPlaceHolderApiTest.updateTest2(id, name, age);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Test>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Test> call, Response<Test> response) {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityTest.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Test> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityTest.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```